# c++ create a temporary thread object does not start a new thread

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void f() {
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::thread(f);
    while(true) {}
}
```

Running above code hangs forever as I expected, but it doesn't print anything. if `thread(f)` is replaced with `thread t(f)`, it prints `hello`. Does this mean my compiler has a bug? I'm using gcc 7.2.1 on arch linux.

Comment: `thread` is class not a function, therefore this didn't work.

Comment: @Mohit: `std::thread` can be constructed from a function, can't it?

Comment: @einpoklum: you need a reference to the thread object

Comment: @Mohit: No I don't, this code compiles fine.

Comment: @TypeIA: It's not a dupe; and running this code, you don't even get the terminate called.